# WPF control for rich content + embedded buttons

Tags: wpf

I am completely new to WPF and looking for a control that will hold rich content, by which I mean

- Formatted text
- Pictures
- Embedded buttons (this can also by images made clickable)

What's the control I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to handle your requirements with a [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Any control which supports display of `FlowDocument` content, such as a [`FlowDocumentScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (if you need editing) would work.

Comment: Thank you. Can a FlowDocument display XAML markup generated dynamically at runtime?

Comment: @user3033490 You can add elements (runs/paragraphs/etc) to it at runtime

Comment: Yes, but I cannot feed raw XAML into the FlowDocument at runtime? (Just like you can do it with a browser control.)

Comment: @user3033490 Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751864(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @user3033490 Or, alternatively, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753299(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Great, I were unaware of FlowDocument, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed a Browser Control..

Definition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Example:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/webbrowser-wpf